# Is it a problem to have 2 version of MySql.Data assemblies in GAC?

Tags: .net, mysql, assemblies, gacutil

I have 2 versions MySql.Data assemblies  in GAC

The Global Assembly Cache contains the following assemblies:
  MySql.Data, Version=5.2.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d,
 processorArchitecture=MSIL
  MySql.Data, Version=6.4.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d,
 processorArchitecture=MSIL

Will they be conflicting with each other when my class library try to find MySql.Data ?

I used gacutil to register the verion 6.4.3.0 as follow:

```
gacutil /i MySql.Data.dll
```

If I want to manual unregister assembly of a particular version , what is the command line to do it via gacutil ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a problem, GAC is there to version all assemblies registered in there and is able to handle this by definition. Consuming applications can absolutely specify which version they want to use so the installation of a newer assembly in the GAC will not break existing application which need to reference older versions.

Comment: Thanks! How unregistered a specific version of the assembly ?

Comment: MSDN is your friend: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559881(v=bts.20).aspx